# Error in swapping two strings

Tags: python

Getting an error in swapping two strings character-wise...

Code:

```
#Exchange names using 2-D array of characters

names=["akshay","parag","raman","srinivas","gopal","rajesh"]

      print "Original:%s %s\n" % (names[2],names[3])

for i in range(0,10,1):
      t=names[2][i]
      names[2][i]=names[3][i]
      names[3][i]=t
      print "New:%s %s\n" % (names[2],names[3])

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Any solution for that?

Comment: FYI, Python allows you to swap like such: `a, b = b, a`.

Comment: Strings are immutable and (as the interpreter helpfully explains) do not support item assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`names` is a list of strings. So when you do `names[2][someIndex]` you are accessing *a single character* of that string. So when you do `names[2][i] = names[3][i]` you are trying to swap two characters. Because Python strings are immutable, this does not work.

Apart from that, you are also trying to access an index of that string which won’t exist. For example `names[2]` is `raman`, so 5 characters long. Because you are looping `i` up to `9`, you would eventually try to access `'raman'[5]`, `'raman'[6]`, …, `'raman'[9]` which all would raise a IndexError.

If you want to swap two strings in a list, just swap the strings as a whole:

```
>>> names = ["akshay","parag","raman","srinivas","gopal","rajesh"]
>>> t = names[2]
>>> names[2] = names[3]
>>> names[3] = t
```

Or in short, without a temporary variable:

```
>>> names[2], names[3] = names[3], names[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Python, you can use [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) here:

```
names = map(bytearray, names)
print "Original:%s %s\n" % (names[2],names[3])
for i in range(10):
    try:
        #That's how we swap items in Python.
        names[2][i],  names[3][i] = names[3][i], names[2][i]
    except IndexError:
        #'raman' will raise error for index 5, so we need to catch that here
        #Do someting here for unequal strings or break
        break

print "New:%s %s\n" % (names[2],names[3])
```

You cannot update a string, all you can do is create a new string using either the string methods or slicing etc.

**Update:**

```
names = map(bytearray, names)
print "Original:%s %s\n" % (names[2],names[3])
s = sorted((names[2], names[3]), key=len)
for i in range(len(s[1])):
    try:
        # Here in case of unequal length string, s[0] is the shorter string
        # and s[1] is the longer one.
        s[0][i], s[1][i] = s[1][i], s[0][i]
    except IndexError:
        for _ in range(i, len(s[1])):
            #remove the items from the longer string and append them to the shorter one.
            s[0].append(s[1].pop(i))            

print "New:%s %s\n" % (names[2],names[3])
```

---

Also note that `bytearray` is fine only if you use it with ASCII characters, don't use it with non-ASCII data.

Comment: Don't use a `bytearray`. Bytes may not correspond to characters. Taking the first ten bytes of, say, 中国话不用彁字。, will not get you what you expect. Woe unto you if you take part of a character!

Comment: it is giving wrong output... skipping some part of name...


Original:raman srinivas

New:srini ramanvas

Comment: @user3223301  I didn't change the logic of the program, it is still doing what you were trying to do in the original code. What was you expected output here?

Comment: @kindall That's true, but if OP data contain only ASCII then there's no harm in using a `bytearray`. But, yes I should add a warning related to this.

Comment: expected output: 


Original:raman srinivas

New:srinivas raman

Comment: @user3223301 Well in that case you should go with poke's answer, that's the best way to do this in Python.

Comment: @user3223301 I've posted a horrific working version of the code, but as I said go with poke's answer. :)

Comment: As an alternative to using bytearrays, you could also convert the string to a list of characters, do the swapping, and then convert it back. But that’s definitely not pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

This swaps `names[2]` and `names[3]` in one line, correctly:

```
names[2], names[3] = names[3], names[2] # they are swapped - a,b = b,a
```

Comment: Why do you still include the failing code in your answer, making it appear as if that’s the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If each of your strings is at least 10 characters, you can do this without a loop at all:

```
names[2], names[3] = names[3][:10] + names[2][10:], names[2][:10] + names[3][10:]
```

This does both assignments at once. After this, `names[2]` will have the first 10 letters of `names[3]` and the letters of `names[2]` from position 10 on. And similarly for `names[3]`.